# React Native Elements throwing 'JSX component' error after upgrading packages

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I am facing an issue with my React Native project after upgrading some of my dependencies. All of the react-native elements, such as TextInput, are showing the following error:

```
'TextInput' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type 'typeof TextInput' is not a valid JSX element type.ts(2786)
```

Here are the relevant details of my project:

**Package.json:**

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    // ... other dependencies
    "expo": "49.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    // ... other dependencies
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.19.3",
    "@types/react": "18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.2"
  },
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have tried several solutions such as cleaning the project, rebuilding it, and checking for breaking changes in the React Native Elements documentation, but the issue persists.

Any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by re-installing version 18

```
npm i react@18 react-dom@18 @types/react@18 @types/react-dom@18
```

and it updates/changes the package from:
@types/react-dom 18.2.0 -> ^18.2.18